# What is the expression for derivative of the signum function one should use in the BP training method

Tags: machine-learning, backpropagation, derivative, perceptron

The back propagation learning method requires knowing of derivatives of activation functions. But what expression one should use for signum activation function
$$
    \mathrm{Signum}( x ) = 
    \begin{cases}
        1, &x \geq \gamma\\
        0, &x < \gamma
    \end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 4):

The function you wrote is completely flat, except at $x=\gamma$ where the step occurs. So, its derivative w.r.t. $x$ is zero everywhere, except at $x=\gamma$, where the derivative doesn't exist. This means gradients (whenever they exist) will always be zero, and gradient-based learning rules (e.g. backprop) won't work. If you want learning to happen, you'd have to use a non-flat activation function or a learning rule that isn't based on gradients.

Comment: As an addition to the answer: you can use the [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) function which could be used as an approximation to the Signum. And its has a finite derivative everywhere.